# Array Issue in Objective C Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, algorithm

I have a problem with my algorithm for calculating a sore.  The user enters a word into the UITextField, and if the word matches a string in the array (@"The Word") the int 'score' will be added by 1.

Then the int score is set as a label as the user gets a word right.  (DISPLAYING THE SCORE)

THE PROBLEM, a user can just keep on entering the same word over and over again and the score will keep going up by one.  IS there a command for knowing if a word has already been entered, so you can only use the word once.

The Code

```
 NSArray *scoreArray1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
@"Word 1", @"Word 2", @"Word 3", nil];

NSString *inputtwo =_EnterNameText.text;
BOOL isItright = NO;
for(NSString *possible in scoreArray1) {
    if([inputtwo isEqual:possible] ) {
        isItright = YES;
        break;
    }
}

if(isItright) {

    static int myInt = 0;
    myInt++;
    NSString *score = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myInt];
    [_scorelabel setText:score];

}
```

UPDATE!!!!!!

```
    NSArray *scoreArray1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
@"Alan Shearer", @"Shearer", @"Andrew Cole", @"Andy Cole", @"Cole", @"Thierry Henry", @"Henry", @"Robbie Fowler", @"Fowler", @"Frank Lampard", @"Lampard", @"Michael Owen", @"Owen", nil];

NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithArray:scoreArray1];



NSString *inputtwo =_EnterNameText.text;
BOOL isItright = NO;
for(NSString *possible in set2) {
    if([inputtwo isEqual:possible] ) {
        isItright = YES;
        break;
    }
}

if(isItright) {

    static int myInt = 0;
    myInt++;
    NSString *score = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myInt];
    [_scorelabel setText:score];

}
```

HOWEVER NOW THE APP DOES NOT WORK, IT CRASHES, any suggestions?

Comment: You obviously need to keep a list of already-entered words.  This implies some sort of dictionary or hashtable to find out if a word is in the list (rather than having to search the entire list each time).

Comment: (However, if you only have a very short list of possible words, you can simply use a boolean array with a bit for each possible word.)

Comment: You will need to have some sort of data structure to keep a list of guessed words. And then in your `if(isItright)` statement, add the condition that the word has not been guessed before.

Comment: I am new to Xcode, can you either tell me how to do this or point me in the direction of a good tutorial for Xcode 4.5.1?

Comment: I have a lot of words, I just scaled down the issue in this question

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you keep a second Array where you store the given (correct) answers.
Whit this you can just do a contains inside your if....problem solved.

a second option is not to put string in your array but "Answer" Objects, that have a field that you can flag as already used.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create an NSMutableSet and put a copy of the word into there whenever one is entered. Then you just need to check if the word exists in the set before incrementing the score.

I'm suggesting a set because it uses hashed access, so lookups are fast. Also, if you add the same string more than once, the set will still only have one reference to the string.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you have an array of "legal" words, the way to go is to simply remove each word as it's called out, until the array gets to be zero entries long.

```
NSMutableArray* scoreArrayCopy = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:scoreArray];
int originalCount = scoreArrayCopy.count;
...
while (scoreArrayCopy.count > 0) {
   NSString* guess = <get next guess>;
   [scoreArrayCopy removeObject:guess];
   score = originalCount - scoreArrayCopy.count;
}
```

(If you have a lot of words things would be more efficient if you used an NSMutableSet instead of an NSMutableArray, but the logic would be the same.)

Comment: What does the line "NSString *guess = <get next guess>; mean?

Comment: @JeevanThandi -- That would be the logic to get the user's guess from the text field.  Of course, you can't wait on the user inside that loop, so you have to unroll it into a simple state machine, like any other UI app.  The above is the "conceptual" model.

Comment: I have added the code you suggested and I get the error http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2946hog&s=6

Comment: Hmmm... I could have sworn there was a `mutableArray` method on NSArray.  Well, use `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:scoreArray]`.  (But technically it should probably be redeclared -- I'll update the post.)

Comment: Thank you, there are now no errors however my app just freezes when it executes the IBAction associated with the "Check if correct" button :(

Comment: @JeevanThandi -- Like I said, you need to recast the above logic into a state machine, suitable for use with the UI.  You can't just take the code literally and plug it in.